# Flexline on a t and p release valve?

Tags: pipe, valve, temperature, pressure

Opened new water heater box and noticed that the t and p valve is in the wrong place...on top. It used to be connected on the side with a copper flexline, then 3/4 copper pipe through a kitchen party wall, discharging to the outside. This is in a condo, i.r. open system.

It would be easy to add nipples and another copper flexline to reconnect all at the top. Seeing as how I'm in earthquake country (WA), the flexline makes sense. However, I need to know if this entire discharge line must be ridgid pipe...or can it include two flexlines and the ridgid copper pipe?

I envision the extension -- if all rigid--to contain only two 90 degree angles of 3/4 inch pipe. Otherwise, I'd prefer to use the two flexlines.
Anyone know if a second flexline is okay, whether one is okay or whether it must all be rigid pipe?

Since drafting this I decided to just move the t and p valve but still interested in answers to my questions!

Comment: Can you post a photo or drawing of the proposed T&P drain route?

Comment: Two points: 1) You've got an existing flex line, if you plumb hard lines from the WH to the flex line, you still have flexibility between the heater and the wall to accommodate earthquakes. 2) You're going to move the valve on a brand new water heater to accommodate existing plumbing? You're aware that will probably void your warranty immediately, right?

Comment: I was not proposing to put in hard lines from the water heater to a flex line at all. Plan A: using a new flexiline at top of heater to reach second, existing flexline at the side, which then connects to existing hardline. Plan B was to put in hardline all the way through for t and p. Haven't moved s thing yet as I need more parts. THANKS for warranty tip!!!

Comment: I checked with manufacturer and read the warranty and there is no verbiage about voiding the warranty if I relocate the t and p valve. Indeed, they provide a second, side port location for it.